# Are there any port(s) & IPs I need opened in my private server's firewall for Cloud Functions requests to go through?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Assistant Action that uses Cloud Functions and in that Action I need to send GET/POST requests to my private server.

We're using Thingworx platform for development and it is hosted on a private cloud behind a firewall.

I've also tried Postman to send these requests and it worked perfectly, but when I use the same on my Google Assistant Action, it just doesn't work and all I get is an empty response.

My request code is below:

```
function callMeAPI(agent) {
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://{IP:Port}/Thingworx/Things/{Path}',
  qs: { appKey: 'AppKey Used Here' },
  headers: 
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     Accept: 'application/json' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
  agent.add("body");
});
```

So, are there any ports and IPs/URLs we need to add to our firewall rules to add for requests originating from Cloud Functions to go through the firewall onto our Thingworx Application?

Answer (score 0):

You should not make any assumptions about the IP address of outbound traffic originating from Cloud Functions.  The originating IP could change over time, depending on Google infrastructure, and also based on which region your function was deployed to.

If you need to ensure that access to your network originated from your function, you should implement some sort of authentication in the request so that your own application can validate the request.  Typically, there is some shared secret that only both sides know that indicate they are aware of each other.

Comment: So, since Firebase dynamically allocates its IP like the other Google services (i.e. Google Maps), could I just whitelist "firebase.google.com" to allow its connection to our cloud? Also, does Firebase use specific ports for its Functions like it does for FCM (5228)?

Comment: It's not dynamically allocating IPs.  It's just not guaranteed to be from a given IP range at any given moment in time. Originating ports are never guaranteed.